# github no me deja hacer push en ubuntu

Tags: linux, netbeans, ubuntu, git, github

Tengo un proyecto en "github" y trabajo en el con windows y Ubuntu. Con windows si puedo hacer push pero en Ubuntu no puedo. Ya cree el token y en windows me funciona pero ahora el problema lo tengo en Ubuntu que no me deja.
Probé a crear un repositorio nuevo y clonarlo, al hacerlo puse el token de contraseña pero tampoco me deja hacer Push.
¿Alguna idea que puedo estar haciendo mal?

---

Yo los permisos los puse a 777 'ya se que no se debe' te pongo lo que me responde con tú comando:

```
drwxrwsr-x 5 carlos www-data 4096 oct  8 15:16 .
drwxrwsrwx 3 carlos www-data 4096 oct  8 15:06 ..
drwxr-sr-x 2 carlos www-data 4096 oct  8 15:15 Carpeta sin título
drwxrwsr-x 8 carlos www-data 4096 oct  8 15:18 .git
drwxrwsrwx 3 carlos www-data 4096 oct  4 23:18 nbproject
```

He intentado hacer lo que pone en la documentación de git:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

Me clona **sin preguntarme usuario y contraseña** que mala suerte.

Comment: ¿Qué comandos estás usando y qué error tienes en la consola?

Comment: Si, por favor, coloca el comando y su salida en la pregunta para saber qué dice git al respecto.